# Subsequences in recurrent sequence

Tags: limits

I need to prove convergence for $$x_1=-3,x_{n+1}=1+\frac{6}{x_n} $$ I see that sequence is bounded and there is 2 subsequences with even and odd numbers. One is decreasing and another is increasing and it looks like they both have the same lim. But I wonder how can I prove all this things.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Every bounded, monotonic sequence of real numbers is convergent.

Comment: Yes. I understand but how can I show that there is really 2 monotonic subsequences? I failed in using induction.